# Twilio How to Play a Message on Caller Parties End?

Tags: twilio

I was able to implement call whisper using twilio api (runs/plays message on called parties) end using this.

```
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Number url="call_whisper_url">
            415-123-4567
        </Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Where `call_whisper_url` contains the `<Say>` verb. All good.

But how do I play something on callers end? If I do something like this.

```
<Response>
    <Say>Play for Caller</Say>
    <Dial>
        <Number url="call_whisper_url">
            415-123-4567
        </Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

It will first play the message then initiate the call. How can I do it simultaneously, meaning: Twilio will initiate the call while playing the `<Say>` verb? Or it is the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0):

After investigating it some days. I have not found other ways of doing it. So, I will add what I am doing currently as an answer.

```
<Response>
    <Say>Play for Caller</Say>
    <Dial>
        <Number url="call_whisper_url">
            415-123-4567
        </Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

If anybody have better solution please add the answer.